# Java Regex matchs() is returning false but works in browser

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a regex expression

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(watch\?(.*&)?v=|(embed|v)\/))([^\?&"'>]+)
```

when I run it against http://youtu.be/QlgDPA9o21A in the browser it is matching but 
not in java

here is the code

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(https?:\\/\\/)?(www/.)?(youtu\\.be\\/|youtube\\.com\\/(watch\\?(.*&)?v=|(embed|v)\\/))([^\\?&\"'>]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

    if (matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() == 7) {
        return matcher.group(7);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The code works for me. Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you don't need to escape every forward slash.

like you're doing `\\/` should be just `/`

Your pattern will be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(https?://)?(www\\.)?(youtu\\.be/|youtube\\.com/(watch\\?(.*&)?v=|(embed|v)/))([^\\?&\"'>]+)");
```

Comment: Escaping wouldn't cause a regex pattern to stop working though

Comment: While reading closely I found few other issues that I have fixed e.g. `(www\\.)` instead of `(www/.)`